# Value of complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Detemine the value of the integral
$$
\int\limits_\gamma e^{4z+1}dz
$$

where $\gamma$ is any circle of radius $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ in $\mathbb{C}$, oriented counter-clockwise. (**5 marks**)

I can't see any singularities here, so does that mean I can  use Cauchy's theorem on this?

Comment: Function under integral belongs to $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})$, so...

Comment: The "*any* circle" bit should be a hint that you indeed use $\oint_\gamma fdz=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that this integral should be zero by Cauchy's integral theorem but I suppose they want you to compute it. So here it goes:

Set $r := \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\gamma (t) := r e^{i t}$. Then 
$$ \oint f(z) dz = \int_0^{2 \pi} f(\gamma) \dot{\gamma}(t) dt = \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{4r (\cos t + i \sin t) + 1} r(i \cos t -  \sin t) dt $$

Then $$ \frac{d}{dt}\left ( e^{4r (\cos t + i \sin t) + 1} \right ) = e^{4r (\cos t + i \sin t) + 1} 4r(i \cos t -  \sin t)$$

So $$ \oint f(z) dz = \left [ \frac{1}{4}  e^{4r (\cos t + i \sin t) + 1} \right ]_0^{2 \pi} = \left [ \frac{1}{4}  e^{4r e^{it} + 1} \right ]_0^{2 \pi} = 0 $$